# Loading individual apache conf files on the fly

Tags: apache-2.2, web-server

I need to be able to tell apache to load a new conf file without all of the config being reloaded. This is because I will have many conf files and it will take 10 minutes to load them all.

basically what I want to do is 'httpd load newsite.conf'. Equally it would be nice to be able to unload a conf file that is already loaded but that is not a requirement.

I've searched and searched and I can't find the answer anywhere, I can't believe there isn't one?

Failing that, is there a way to speed up a 'httpd reload' command?

Thanks in advance! :]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be of interest: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/mass.html

Also, .htaccess files would allow you to make changes without reloading the entire config.

Comment: Absolutely! thank you. The VirtualDocumentRoot will solve our immediate problem. The htaccess solution still requires a mapping file which will be huge with 100,000+ vhosts, probably worse in fact as that will be hit per request rather than at server load. I don't know why this page illuded me when I was searching, thank you very much for taking the time to post :]